# When should one prefer ThreadLocal over synchronization, apart from for the performance improvement?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local

When should one prefer `ThreadLocal` over synchronization, apart from for the performance improvement? Please explain using a real life example.

Comment: Something which I've read -  you can use it to share otherwise non thread safe class in a thread safe way. There are plenty of `SimpleDateFormat` examples can be found over internet.

Answer (score 3):

When you use ThreadLocal variables these are seen and manipulated by the thread using it ONLY, no other thread can see them. Thread local variables dies when the thread does too.
And one should be careful then using ThreadLocal variables when using thread pools.

ThreadLocal variables are put in a special memory space called Thread private stack.

Shared variable are put in the heap memory space where they are shared among all threads and they are either synchronized or not.

So it is more about use case than performance.

One can use ThreadLocal variable to hold a connection to some DB where the connection is associated with the current thread ONLY and no need for other thread to see it and a need to synchronize it. The cache - a shared in memory map or list,for example, however, is shared among all threads in a server application and it must be synchronized.

Answer (score 3):

`ThreadLocal` is not an alternative to `synchronized`.  The main problem solved by `ThreadLocal` is how to manage per-thread `static` data in an application.

`static` is something that you should try to avoid whenever you can:  It's a recipe for un-testable, brittle code.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason to use Threads is for performance reasons (or perhaps you like confusion ;).

AFAICS If you discount performance, there is not reason to use Threads, ThreadLocal nor synchronzied.

Comment: Performance is not the only reason to use threads.  It's not even the original reason.  Multi-threaded programs were used in the real world long before multi-processor hardware escaped from the lab.  Threads were meant to be a cleaner alternative to event-driven programming---a way to structure programs that respond to multiple, asynchronous inputs:  Each thread listens to just one input source, and handles events in a purely synchronous, procedural manner, keeping state in local variables.  Easy to understand... right up until the point where you need the threads to talk to each other.

Answer (score 0):

ThreadLocal provides global variable access with in a Thread. This will help when you want to share a variable across methods and still retain Thread scope.

J2EE application servers use ThreadLocal for tracking Transaction, Security context with out passing around